# What is the 'form' of teaching ('pattern of 2 Tim 1:13) in Romans 6:17?

Tags: teaching

Is this a catechism - a set construction of teaching? Why not just say ... 'the teachings which you were committed'?

Comment: See also . . . . _He that abideth in **the doctrine of Christ**, he hath both the Father and the Son._ (2 John 1:9) . . . _And they continued steadfastly in **the apostles' doctrine**_  (Acts 2:42). There is a **structure** to the conveying of the information which is as important as the content itself.

Answer (score 1):

What Paul is talking about in 2 Tim 1:13, is simply the complex of his teachings. The word he uses in these verses for "form" is an unusual one. Ὑποτύπωσιν can just as aptly be translated "example." So, whatever Paul committed to them as instruction was to be held on to as "sound words" which he declares are rooted in Christ Jesus.

The word in Romans 6:17 - τύπον - is a more common word for "form" in the NT and the meaning is not related to that of Ὑποτύπωσιν. τύπον typically refers more to something that represents a copy, a type, or a figure of something else. With that in mind, Paul is saying that baptism then is a representation of the death, burial, and resurrection of Christ.

Another word that is commonly translated as form is μορφῇ, as in Phil 2:6, and usually refers to the form or shape of a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but, the Gk of Rom 6:17 is aorist passive indicative which, it seems to me,  literally is not the teaching that was given to them, but the teaching unto which they were delivered. The implication being that there was a teaching (body of teaching?) which Paul committed them to.  Deliverance from slavery to sin was the effect of them being handed over to a body of teaching objectively, rather than those who had been delivered receiving teaching from Paul subjectively. In 2 Timothy 1:13 it is aorist active indicative which does mean the pattern of teaching that was given to them by Paul. Perhaps there is no difference but it is this that I am thinking through with its implications for discipleship and teaching in the church today.

Answer (score 0):

What is the pattern of sound words in 2 Timothy 1:13?

Paul urged his coworker Timothy: “Keep holding the pattern of sound words that you heard from me with the faith and love that are in connection with Christ Jesus.” (2 Timothy 1:13) What did Paul mean? The Greek word here rendered “pattern” literally refers to a sketch. Although not overly detailed, such a representation has well-defined boundaries so that a discerning viewer can perceive the overall picture. Similarly, the pattern of truth that Paul taught Timothy and others was not designed to give a specific answer to every conceivable question. Yet, this body of teaching provides sufficient guidance​—an outline, as it were—​so that honesthearted ones can perceive what God requires of them. To please God, of course, they would need to keep holding to that pattern of truth by practicing what they have learned.

How can Christians stick to the pattern of sound words?

In the first century, such individuals as Hymenaeus, Alexander, and Philetus were advocating ideas that did not fit “the pattern of sound words.” (1 Timothy 1:18-20; 2 Timothy 2:16, 17) How could the early Christians avoid being led astray by apostates? By carefully studying the inspired writings and applying them in life. Those walking in accord with the example they had in Paul and other faithful ones were able to recognize and reject anything that did not conform to the pattern of truth they had been taught. (Philippians 3:17; Hebrews 5:14) Instead of being “mentally diseased over questionings and debates about words,” they continued moving ahead in their positive course of godly devotion. (1 Timothy 6:3-6)

Romans 6:17 YLT says, and thanks to God, that ye were servants of the sin, and -- were obedient from the heart to the form of teaching to which ye were delivered up;

The apostle Paul wrote to Christians in Rome: “Thanks to God that you were the slaves of sin but you became obedient from the heart to that form of teaching to which you were handed over.” Those who hear with a good heart and obey are not here told that the “good news” was handed over to them, but that they were ‘handed over to that form of teaching,’ the gospel or good news of the Kingdom. They are now willing subjects and supporters of God’s sovereignty. When they, in turn, proclaim the “good news,” the receivers are handed over to such teaching. For, instead of their former uncleanness and lawlessness, these ‘now present their body members as slaves to righteousness.’​—Rom. 6:17-19.